# Is there a university that accepts students for CS Masters Degree without needing Bachelor's degree?

Tags: education

I am looking for a university/college that offers courses in English language and accepts students for Masters Degree in Computer Science and/or Mathematics without asking for a Bachelor's Degree. I have been studying online (doing courses from Coursera, EdX etc.) and have about the same knowledge as undergraduate students. So, does such university exist or should I just forget about it? Is there any way I can get accepted in any Graduate level studies in the above mentioned fields without having a bachelor's degree?

p.s. I hope I am asking this question in a right place (if I'm not, please let me know and I will delete it).

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this is on-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange. Here, we only consider questions about computer science, as distinct from questions about studying the subject. [Academia.se] doesn't give lists or recommendations of universities. In general, though, I suspect you'll find it difficult to get accepted onto a master's course without a bachelor's degree or equivalent professional experience. You'll need a way of convincing them that your studies so far really are equivalent to a bachelor's degree.

Comment: I think most places have a procedure. Check out MIT's [Advanced Standing Examinations](https://web.mit.edu/registrar/classrooms/exams/ase_exams.html) -

> Students may take an ASE to **earn credit for an MIT subject without taking the subject**. To be eligible to take an ASE, students must have neither attended nor been registered for the subject in question, or any of its variations.

Comment: @Rob, ASE exams are only for MIT students (who have already been admitted and enrolled), so not really relevant here.  I would expect the same to be true at many places.

Comment: Error in that URL, it's: http://web.mit.edu/registrar/classrooms/exams/ase_exams.html - There's no mention of admission or enrollment. As has been suggested there's no where to ask on SE, and this question is held/closed, best to phone admissions at the place you intend to attend.